# Session variable is not displayed online but displayed locally

Tags: php, session, session-variables

In the bellow code i have printed a session variable on the output page

```
<?php ob_start();
session_start();
include("database.php");
include("tracking-header.php");
?>
<div class="dt-content" style="text-align:center;">
<p class="srymsg">Sorry</p>
<p class="srymsg2" style="margin-bottom:110px;">The Vehicle number <span style="color:#000; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;"><?php print $_SESSION['vehicleno']; ?></span>, not found.<br />please try again.</p>
 </div>
<div class="nxtbtn" >
<a href="tracking-system-a.php"><input type="button" value="BACK" name="back" style="float:left;margin:17px 25px 16px;"  /></a>
<?php include("tracking-footer.php");?>
```

in this `print $_SESSION['vehicleno'];` is displayed on local but when i upload this file online and then this is not displayed on the page. can any one say what is the problem in it?

Comment: where in the code have you set this session variable?

Comment: When is the $_SESSION variable being created? Have you verified that it is being created correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try by switching place of ob_start and session_start function like below

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
include("database.php");
include("tracking-header.php");
?>
<div class="dt-content" style="text-align:center;">
<p class="srymsg">Sorry</p>
<p class="srymsg2" style="margin-bottom:110px;">The Vehicle number <span style="color:#000; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;"><?php print $_SESSION['vehicleno']; ?></span>, not found.<br />please try again.</p>
 </div>
<div class="nxtbtn" >
<a href="tracking-system-a.php"><input type="button" value="BACK" name="back" style="float:left;margin:17px 25px 16px;"  /></a>
<?php include("tracking-footer.php");?>
```

Comment: @Hardeep Pandya Do you mean session won't work if it not at first line

Comment: @PavanKumar I just said to try in this way. That doesn't mean session_start wont work if after ob_start function.